# Producer-consumer pattern in ant

Tags: ant

This is not strictly a producer-consumer pattern, but this is close enough to describe my problem.

I have a list of items that need to be consumed by N processes. I would like to allocate a process number to an item as soon as it is free, rather than hard-code the order.

For example, to run a test, one would call:

```
<runTest target="t1">
    <property name="instance" value="i1" />
</runTest>
```

If I had `i1` to `i3` in hand, and `t1` to `t10` tests to run, I could do:

```
<parallel>
    <runTest target="t1">
        <property name="instance" value="i1" />
    </runTest>
    <runTest target="t2">
        <property name="instance" value="i2" />
    </runTest>
    <runTest target="t3">
        <property name="instance" value="i3" />
    </runTest>
<parallel>
```

I would then wait for this to complete and run the same with different targets. I could also loop this whole code to reduce the tediousness. But is it possible to pick up a target and supply it to an instance as soon as it is done with the previous target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [parallel](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html) task and the [for](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) task are too primitive to handle this type of requirement, if one is hellbent on using Ant, my view is that a new ant task (tutorial [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html)) should be written to handle this behavior.

I also realized we could use the "script" task to write a short piece of code in, say Ruby or Javascript, to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this problem would be easier to solve outside of ANT?

I would recommend looking at an automated build engine like Jenkins. It has the ability to delegate build jobs out to a pool of worker processes, either running locally or on "slave" nodes. Jenkins also has a number of process work-flow plugins that enable jobs to be run based on the success or failure of other jobs. This is how Continuous Integration/Delivery pipelines are implemented.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree, I already had solved this outside of ant, but due to technical constraints, I am being forced to implement this in Ant itself.